# Clojure swapping elements in an input sequence

Tags: clojure, sequence, swap

How do you swap adjacent elements in an input sequence using clojure.
[10 15 20 25] ---> [15 10 25 20]
[:q :e :g :t :p] ---> [:e :q :t :g :p]

this is how i did it, but pretty sure there are better ways to do it!

```
(defn switch [s]
(loop [[a b & rest] s
       result []]
  (if (empty? rest)
    (cond
        ;;empty sequence
        (empty? s) result
        ;;odd sequence
        (nil? b) (conj result a)
        ;;even sequence
        :else (conj result b a)
    )
    (recur rest (conj result b a))))
    )
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because:  It appears to be a simple homework problem.

Comment: Show the work you have done so far.

Comment: @AlanThompson That is not the official Stack Overflow [policy on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). We care about questions that are well asked, and that is independent of whether they are homework. This one looks fine to me, as it clearly defines the desired behavior and shows an attempt. It's even a working attempt, asking for ways to do it better.

Comment: The first line was the only thing present when first posted

Answer (score 2):

```
(let [A [:q :e :g :t :p]]
    (->> A
         (partition-all 2)
         (mapcat reverse)))
```

Comment: `(map reverse)` + `flatten` == `(mapcat reverse)`

Comment: Indeed. It is more succinct your way.

Comment: It's not just more succinct, but more correct. `flatten` is (almost) never the right answer. Imagine if A were instead defined as `[[1 2] [3 4]]`. We'd like the result to be `[[3 4] [1 2]]`, but with the `flatten` version we would get `[3 4 1 2]`.